# I'm Missing Something on Problem 3 in Section A5.4 of Bruhn's Analysis and Design of Airplane Structures

Tags: structural-engineering, aerospace-engineering, structures

I've been working through the 1943 edition of Bruhn's Analysis and Design of Airplane Structures. I found an archive.org pdf version of the 1948 edition that includes answers to select problems, as well (https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.166811/page/n509/mode/2up, page 510 of the PDF). I've generally found myself getting answers within rounding errors (the joys of modern calculators vs. old tabulated data with interpolation).
However, I am working problem 3 in A5.4, Torsional Stresses and Deflections (thin-walled closed sections). My solution follows the general structure of example A5.12, but I'm coming up with the wrong answers. Per the solutions, I should be seeing shear flow of 159.6 in the large cell, and 149.6 in the small cell, with a theta of .0118 rad. Instead, I am getting 179.8 lb/inch, and 193.1 lb/inch, with a theta of .0166 rad.
Here is the general example I am using to apply here:
[image: generalized example]
Here is the problem (note thicknesses are hard to see in the PDF, left cell is .04, right cell is .045, web in between is .035):
[image: problem]
And here is how I'm working it

```
a_10 = l_10/t_10
where l_10 = 5+5 + (7*pi) ~32, and t_10 = .04
a_10 = 800

a_12 = l_12/t_12, where l_12=7, t_12=.035
a_12 = 200

a_20 = l_20/t_20, where l_20 = 7*pi ~ 22, t_20 = .045
a_20 = 488.7

A1 = 5*7 + (pi*7^2/2) = 112
A2  = pi*7^2/2 = 77
A = A1+A2 = 189

q1 = 1/2*[(a_20*A1 + a_12*A)/(a_20*A1^2 + a_12*A^2 + a_10*A2^2)]*70,000 = 180 lb/inch
q2 = 1/2*[(a_10*A2 + a_12*A)/(a_20*A1^2 + a_12*A^2 + a_10*A2^2)]*70,000 = 193.1 lb/inch
J = 4 * [ (a_20*A1^2 + a_12*A^2 + a_10*A2^2)/(a_10*a_12 + a_12*a_20 + a_20*a10)] = 111.1
theta = T/(G*J) = 70,000/(3,800,000*111.1) = .000166 rad/inch. 
.000166rad/inch * 100 inches = .0166 rad.
```

What am I missing here? These equations pull directly from the previous page, where these are given as generalized equations for a two-celled thin wall closed section.

Here is the answer key: [image]